# File I/O best practice - byte[] or FileStream?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, stream, filestream

I'm currently working with a lot of different file types (txt, binary, office, etc). I typically use a `byte[]` or `string` to hold the file data in memory (while it is being written/parsed) and in order to read/write it into files I write the entire data using a `FileStream` after the data has been completely processed.

- Should I be using a `TextStream` instead of a `string` while generating data for a text file?
- Should I be using a `FileStream` instead of a `byte[]` while generating data for a binary file?
- Would using streams give me better performance instead of calculating the entire data and outputting it in one go at the end?
- Is it a general rule that File I/O should always use streams or is my approach fine in some cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of a byte[]/string vs a stream may be that the byte[]/string is in memory, and accessing it may be faster. If the file is very large, however, you may end up paging thus reducing performance. Another advantage of the byte[]/string approach is that the parsing may be a little easier (simply use File.ReadAllText, say).

If your parsing allows (particularly if you don't need to seek randomly), using a FileStream can be more efficient especially if the file is rather large. Also, you can make use of C#'s (4.5) async/await features to very easily read/write the file asynchronously and process chunks that you read in.

Personally, I'd probably just read the file into memory if I'm not too worried about performance, or the file is very small. Otherwise I'd consider using streams.

Ultimately I would say write some simple test programs and time the performance of each if you're worried about the performance differences, that should give you your best answer.

Comment: A stream is an abstraction over a sequence of data. There is nothing to prevent a Stream for being completely in memory. Hence a MemoryStream.

Comment: Sure, loading the file into a MemoryStream is essentially the same as a byte[], save for the abstraction. However, for the purpose of this question it's worth noting that a FileStream would not load the whole file into memory (save for some buffering etc.).

Comment: @Marcus - can you show some examples with C# async/await features within the context of file I/O?

Comment: @Geotarget: many examples can be found on Microsoft websites themselves, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Apart from talking about the size of the data, another important question is the purpose of the data. Manipulation is easier to perform when working with strings and arrays. If both strings and arrays are equally convenient then an array of bytes would be preferred. Strings have to be interpreted which brings in complexity (Encoding, BOM etc) and therefore increases the likelihood of a bug. Use strings only for text. Binary data should always be handled by byte arrays or streams.

Streams should be considered each time you either don't have to perform any manipulation or the subjected data is very large or the subjected data is coming in very slowly. Streams are a natural way of processing data part by part whereas strings and arrays in general expect the data to be there in its entirety before processing it.

Working in streams will generally yield performance since it opens up the possibility for having different channels both reading and writing asynchronously.

Comment: Updated my answer a bit. It should cover all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

> while generating data for a text file

If the file data flushing is immediate, your choice is [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) over the [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx). If not, then the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

> while generating data for a binary file?

[`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) is a choice. Additionally, [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) over the memstream is preferred.